# Customize beamer headline and sidebar in Palo Alto

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm trying to customize Palo Alto theme from beamer to get something like this:
[image: Title frame]

[image: Frame]

But so far I managed to get this:
[UPDATE]:
Ok, eventually I got this:

```
% Document structure
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=1.25cm]{PaloAlto}
% Titlepage
\title{Basic information about affiliation}
\author[Marcin Lembke]{Autor iksiński}
\institute[]{Instytut Radioelektroniki\\Wydział Elektroniki i Technik Informacyjnych\\Politechnia Warszawska}
\date{Braniewo, 2011}
% Beamer settings
% Resize header
\makeatletter
\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{0.85cm}
\makeatother
% Define colors
\definecolor{primary}{RGB}{200,131,53}
\definecolor{secondary}{RGB}{253,250,200}
% Set colors
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=primary}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=primary}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=secondary}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=primary, fg=black}     %controls the color of the headline
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=secondary}        %controls the color of the sidebar
\setbeamercolor{footer}{bg=primary}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=primary}  %controls the color of the logo area

% Disable navigation bar
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

% Define headline
%\makeatletter
%\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{1cm}
%\makeatother
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@headfade}{1cm}
{%
    color(0cm)=(secondary);
    color(3cm)=(primary);
    color(\paperwidth)=(primary)%
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}}{}
\makeatother
% Define sidebar
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \vspace*{3cm}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    %\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{ire_logo.png}\\
    %\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{weiti_logo.png}\\
    %\includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{pw_logo.png}
    \vspace*{0.1cm}
    \vfill

}
% Define footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{bg=primary}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\ (IRE PW)
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \hfill
            \insertframenumber{}\hspace{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    }
    \makeatletter


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Section}
    \begin{frame}{Frametitle}{Framesubtitle}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So I can resize sidebar and set its colour and include images in it, I can define footer and make some changes (but I don't know how to move frame number to the right side and change canvas colour). I have no idea how to make shading headline and make changes I mentioned before in footer.

Could you help me? Any ideas or advices?
[UPDATE]:
I think it is ok. I still don't know how to change colour of right side of the footer, but it looks good. Thanks @Ignasi for help :)

Comment: Replace `center` option with proper values of `right` or `left` in second footline beamercolobox. You can also split this second beamercolorbox in two, one for title and another for framenumber.

Comment: I cannot help you with `shading`.

Comment: @Ignasi thx, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the footer:

```
% Define footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{bg=primary}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\ (IRE PW)
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \hfill
        \insertframenumber{}\hspace{1ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\makeatletter
```

The line `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}` creates the color box on the bottom right and `title in head/foot` is the color definition in beamer of this box. So you can either redefine the color of this beamer element:

```
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
```

or just replace `title in head/foot` with `author in head/foot` to get the same color as the left box.